# Ember data load model from DS.PromiseArray

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-router

I want to load Ember model using Ember query record.

my code:

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find("user", {username: params.username}).then(function(result){
      return result.get('firstObject');
    });
  },
```

I am using ActiveModel Adapter.

In console i see "generated -> route:login Object {fullName: "route:login"}"

on debugging,  I can see result.get('firstObject') is getting loaded properly but setupController is not called.

Update:

Model is loading fine, I was facing this issue because of bug in controller.
Thanks

Comment: Can you get this up on jsbin?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using two `return` statements in your model hook. If you are going to return data from the `then` function, omit your first `return` statement.

```
model: function(params) {
    this.store.find("user", {username: params.username}).then(function(result){
        return result.get('firstObject');
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this part of code is working fine, I had this issue because of some other reason.

Comment: @awgreenarrow08 - I believe you **have** to have 2 returns in this case. Not explicitly returning from the `model` will not work http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dujuro/1/edit This ain't Ruby ;)

Comment: No... You have to return something in the model hook, or it will just assume the model is null.  The second return is from the promise fulfillment closure, not the model hook closure.